# What about iSCSI for SQL Server?

Tags: san

My IT dept is trying to deploy SAN to store SQL Server data. I google out that there are two solutions, IP SAN(iSCSI) and FC SAN. It's said that FC SAN is much more expensive than IP SAN. Have you ever run SQL Server on iSCSI? Any practice references will be very appreciated.

Leo

Comment: This sounds like the right question for http://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Is the server going to be virtual or physical? If it's going to be virtual it doesn't matter, because most hypervisors will turn the FC connection to an iSCSCI anyway. There is better performance with FC or FCoE than iSCSI in my opinion but mostly it comes down to the cost.

I personally, run my VM and Physical SQL servers with FCoE because of the speed, stability, and cleanliness. If you can afford it, this is the best way to go. But CNA cards and FCoE capable network equipment are really expensive.

If the cost is really the issue, I would go with iSCSI because you shouldn't see a visible difference in performance. Windows already has the MPIO components built-in for connecting the IQNs for iSCSI so you won't have to buy any third party components like Power Path.